# How to remove the original image while dragging?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I'm using HTML5 to drag and drop an image. When I drag it, a transparent clone is generated.

Is it possible to hide the original image? I tried to do it by setting its visibility to "hidden", but it also removes the transparent clone (even when the clone is replaced by another image with `dataTransfer.setDragImage`)

I know that this can be achieved with JQuery, but I'm wondering how (if) it can be done natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution, albeit it's kind of a hack (and thus might not fit everyone's requirements).

**Simply replace the original image's path by the path of a 1*1 transparent pixel during the `dragstart` event, and restore the original path on the `dragend` event.** (You can grab such a pixel from there: http://www.1x1px.me/)

The problem, of course, is that it doesn't really remove the image in the "visibility:gone" sense of the term; there is still an invisible pixel that might cause layout issues. In my case, however, it's fine.